# join() JS for HTML tables

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need to use join() as JS own method to add a table format to the values in those arrays.
This is an example of my two arrays to diplay, and the table layout should look like this.

This is the **part of my code**; ovbiously is not working ok, because Im getting a wrong "L" table style format when it runs.

> I know its look terrible to parse HTML like that, but this code is in
>   Google Apps Scripts, so this table is gonna be send it by email.

Any idea how to get the proper format?

Thanks.

```
|-------|-------|
| user  | skill |
|-------|-------|
| user  | skill |
|-------|-------|

   body +=
      "<table style=" + STYLE.TABLE + ">" +

         outUsers.join("<tr><td style=" + STYLE.TD + ">") + "</td></tr>" +

         outSkills.join("<tr><td style=" + STYLE.TD + ">") + "</td></tr>" +

      "</table>";
```

Comment: You need to HTML-escape your content.

Comment: You have a table within a table. Why? Also, when using `.join()` it puts the glue between each part of your Array, so you should have the ending tags come first then the opening HTML tags after that in the glue. Concatenate the beginning tag and ending tag on both sides of the `join()`ed results.

Comment: It is meant to be a `tbody` I guess.

Comment: cause I was triying to set 2 tables inside one parent table. Did not work eather.

Comment: I think your looking to use a loop, there is probably no reason to join `outUsers` or `outSkills`. I think you want `outUsers[0]` in alignment with `outSkills[0]` showing up in the same `<tr>` as separate `<td>`.

Comment: @PHPglue dammit, you're completely right, I'll have to update my answer, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `Array.prototype.join()` doesn't do the job I'd use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead

Here is an example of what it could look like:

**EDIT *according to [PHPglue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2438423/phpglue) comment*** to have both users and skills on the same row:

```
var body ='';
var outUsers = ['me', 'you', 'her'],
    outSkills = ['eating', 'sleeping', 'working hard'],
    STYLE = {
        TABLE: "border: red;",
        TD: "border: blue;"
    },
    getTR = function (prev, curr, index) {
        return prev + '<tr>' + openingTD + curr + '</td>' + openingTD + outSkills[index] + '</td></tr>';
    };

var openingTD = '<td style="' + STYLE.TD + '">';

body += '<table style="' + STYLE.TABLE + '">' +

         outUsers.reduce(getTR, '') +

        "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time @aduch!! Works great now!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need to see:

```
var table = '<table><tbody>';
for(var i=0,l=outUsers.length; i<l; i++){
  table += '<tr><td>'+outUsers[i]+'</td><td>'+outSkills[i]+'</td></tr>';
}
table += '</tbody></table>';
```

You should style with CSS. You should read my comments above, as well.